# PHP MySQL Insert to is not working for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, database, debugging

I would like help on how to fix why the user info is not inserting into the database. I am not getting any errors printed to the screen and the "Hit" is echoed when I entered info for a user that is not already in the database, so it is reaching that block  of code, just not inserting into the database.

When I echoed $query for values I inputted I recieved INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ( 'tanya', 'long', 'tlong3@twc.com', 'purple03') Nothing appeared when I echoed $result Thanks

```
 <?php  
   session_start();
   require_once("/includes/registerFunctions.php");
   require("/includes/databaseConnection.php");
  ?>
<?php 
$name_message = "";
$password_message = "";
$email_message = "";
$missingInfo = "<div class='message'> Please fix the following errors: ". "<br>"."<ul>";
$numOfErrors = 0;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fname']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['cpassword']);
    $content = array($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $confirm_password);
    $contentMessage = array("First name", "Last name", "email", "password", "confirmation password");
    $length = count($content);
    if(!equalPasswords($password, $confirm_password))
    {
        $missingInfo .= "<li> Passwords do not match </li>";
        $numOfErrors++;
    }
    if(!valid_email($email))
    {
        $missingInfo .= "<li>The entered email is invalid.  </li>";
        $numOfErrors++;

    }
    $min = 8;
    if(strlen($password) < $min || strlen($confirm_password) < $min)
    {
        $missingInfo .= "<li>Please choose a password that is at least ". $min ." characters long </li>";
        $numOfErrors++;
    }


    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        if(!has_presence($content[$i]))
        {
            $missingInfo .= "<li>". ucfirst($contentMessage[$i])." is blank "."<br> </li>";
            $numOfErrors++;
        }

    }
    $missingInfo .= "</ul></div>";


    if($numOfErrors > 0)
    {
        echo $missingInfo;
    }
    $emailQuery = "SELECT  email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $emailResult = mysqli_query($connect, $emailQuery);
    $numOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($emailResult);
    if($numOfErrors == 0 && $numOfRows == 0)
    {
        /* Check if the email is already in use*/
        echo "Hit";

        $query  = "INSERT INTO users (";
        $query .= "  first_name, last_name, email, password";
        $query .= ") VALUES (";
        $query .= "  '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$password}'";
        $query .= ")";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
        if($result)
        {
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $first_name;
            $_SESSION['lname'] = $last_name;


        }

        //$userId = $_SESSION['id']; 
    }
    else if($numOfRows >= 1 )
    {
        echo "The email entered is already in use, please : ". "<a href='index.php'>login</a>";
    }




}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Register</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        form{
            padding-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .message
        {
            position: absolute;
            right: 180px;
            top: 60px;
            width: 220px;
        }
        input {
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            background: transparent;
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
            width: 250px;
        }
        div
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        a
        {
            color: #4169E1;
        }
        a:hover{
            color:grey;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form  id="form" method="POST" action="register.php">
        <h3 style="font-family:'Amatic SC', cursive; font-size: 20px;"> Welcome to Caruize </h3>

        <div >

            <input type="text"  name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div >

            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>

        <div>

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required> 

        </div>

        <div>

            <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off" required> 

        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary"> Register</button> <br> <br>
            <p> Already a member? </p><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="index.php">Sign in </a>
        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pLabel = document.getElementById("passwordLabel");
        pLabel.textContent = "Too Short";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo your complete query and run it from mysql termianl or interface and check the error there

Comment: echo your $query before mysql_query() statement and place that output in question.

Comment: Can you echo $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);?

Comment: INSERT INTO users ( first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ( 'tanya', 'long', 'tlong3@twc.com', 'purple03')    Is what I got when I entered values and echoed  $query.  Nothing appeared when I echoed $result

Comment: please run your query in your phpmyadmin. Check record inserted manually or not.

Comment: I checked it before using the mysql command line, it is not in there. @RuchishParikh

Comment: @kylel9506 is any error occurs after insert into phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I was only inserting values into the database that was required by the form. There were about 5 other fields that I set to NOT NULL that I was not inserting into haha. Thank you all.